# how can i display sql query in php? CLOSED

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php
    include 'config.php'; //connect to db
    if(isset($_REQUEST["pwd"]) && isset($_REQUEST["name"])) {
        $password = $_REQUEST['pwd']; //pass from previous page
        $name = $_REQUEST['name']; //pass from previous page
                $checkUserPass = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM validPersonnel WHERE Passkey = '$password' and Name = '$name'", $conn); //check if the user exist
                if(mysql_num_rows($checkUserPass) == 1) {
                    $personnelId = mysql_query("SELECT PersonnelID FROM validPersonnel WHERE Passkey = '$password' and Name = '$name'", $conn); //query user id
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($personnelId)) {
                        echo $row['PersonnelD']; // print user id
                    }
                    mysql_close($conn);
                    //echo "<br/><br/>";
                    //echo "<script>alert('Logged In.')</script>";
                    //header("Refresh: 1; url=profile/profile.php?id="'.$id.');
                    //header('Refresh: 1; url=test.php?id=$personnelId');
                } else {
                    echo "<br/><br/>";
                    echo "<script>alert('Wrong Password.')</script>";
                    header('Refresh: 1; url=personnelselect.php');
                }
    }
?>
```

i cannot `echo` the `$row['PersonnelD']` the page shows blank. i cannot understand where did i go wrong. this page quesion have been solved

Comment: Why do you query twice? The first would suffice. Also you should be more careful - what if [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) enlists in your company?

Comment: In addition to @kingkero's comment, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5, use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: how to use mysqli or PDO? i have php 5.4++

Comment: This might be nice tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have mistake in code:

```
echo $row['PersonnelD'];
```

shouldn't it be following?

```
echo $row['PersonnelID'];
```

Comment: If you have php debugger you should walk over code, if not, use `var_dump()` or similar to see in which code gets executed. Print your variables which might cause conditional statement to be skipped - usual debugging.

Comment: it displayed array (size=1) 'PersonnelID' => string '4' (length=1) it is the same id in may wamp server

Comment: I suppose you added `var_dump` inside of `while`. That means `echo` should have been called and should have printed **4**. Try `flush()` after echo. Just to be sure. If doesn't help - most likely problem is elsewhere.

Comment: it still doesn't work. however my main problem is to pass the id to the next page. how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

check the mysql_fetch_assoc() function may be its parameter is empty so it can't enter the while loop

Answer (score -1):

Try to debug and check the values came in the variables using `var_dump()` function. Ex: `var_dump($row);` in while loop.

Comment: Is this really an answer? I'd rather call it a comment

Comment: Yes, It may be the comment or suggestion.

Comment: it displayed array (size=1)
  'PersonnelID' => string '4' (length=1)

Comment: it is the same id in may wamp server

Answer (score -2):

In both your querys, you have

```
"SELECT * FROM validPersonnel WHERE Passkey = '$password' and Name = '$name'"
```

It should be:

```
"SELECT * FROM validPersonnel WHERE Passkey = '".$password."' and Name = '".$name."';"
```

PHP doesn't recognize the $var unless you close the quotes. The period adds the $var to the string.

Comment: It is perfectly fine (for the syntax!) to use variables inside double quotes!

Comment: -1, both queries are correct syntax-wise. PHP **will** parse variables enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: where did you get the idea that PHP wouldn't recognize it?

Comment: @DHShah01 double quotes are different from single quotes. For single quotes it wouldn't work.